# Export filled out form as PDF or Word file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, pdf, printing, word-pdf

The users need to be about to print the forms they've filled out on SharePoint after they've filled them out. In just wondering if it is easily possible because I'm not finding anything.

Forms are hosted on SharePoint and created in InfoPath

Answer (score 1):

- Go to list > Customize List> select your form.
- Add a Content Editor Web part or Script Editor for SharePoint 2013 to the page.

[image]
- Add the following code.

```
`< input type="button" value=" Print this page "   onclick="window.print();return false;" />`
```

You can also add `on click` the following function

`function printInfoPathForm(){
         var ipForm = $(INFOPATH_FORM);
            if (ipForm) {
                //build html for print page
                var html = "<HTML><HEAD>\n"+
                    $("head").html()+
                    "</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n"+
                    ipForm.html()+
                    "\n</BODY></HTML>";
                //open new window
                var printWP = window.open("","printWebPart");
                printWP.document.open();
                //insert content
                printWP.document.write(html);
                printWP.document.close();
                //open print dialog
                printWP.print();
            }
        }`

For more details check this [article](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/add-print-button-to-display-form-in-sharepoint-2013-using-20837.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you possibly looked into this: http://infopathprinter.codeplex.com/

You can add the option as a Custom Action XML

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for "Print" button on the form page
Edit the default list form, add "Content Editor" webpart and put the below HTML as content.

you can add css in the same place for formatting.